# Problems using yaml and mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, yaml, snakeyaml

I have a yaml file (third party file that I dont have control over). I need to get this into my mongodb. But when I try inserting it into my collection, I get the below exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Am using snakeyaml to convert my yaml into a Map. One of my nested structure in yaml has keys as double values, and this is what I think is causing the confusion in mongo db.

Am using mongo-java-driver-2.11.3 to interface with mongo

Here is a sample of my yaml file

```
persons:
  - 1st relative:
      name: Alice
      sons:
        - 0:
            name: Alice First son
        - 0.2:
            name: Alice Second son
        - 0.3:
            name: Alice Third son
        - 0.4:
            name: Alice Fourth son
        - 0.5:
           name: Alice Fifth son
```

And here is my simple code to insert into mongo

```
 Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Map<String, Object> object =  (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(new FileInputStream\\test.yaml")));
        coll.insert(new BasicDBObject(object));
```

Any ideas on how to get around this would be much appreciated

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this problem seems to have gone away when I used mongo-java-driver-2.10.0.
I had to go to that version because of my play version which is 2.10.0.

Even though am puzzled as to why it has gone away, am happy it is no more an issue.